# Retrieving the PC Name of a Client? (Windows Auth)

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, authentication

I have an ASP.net Application that runs on the internal network (well, actually it's running on Sharepoint 2007).

I just wonder:

Can I somehow retrieve the name of the PC the Client is using? I would have access to Active Directory if that helps. The thing is, people use multiple PCs. So, I cannot use any manual/static mapping.

If possible, I do not want to use any client-side (read: JavaScript) code, but if it cannot be done server-side, JavaScript would be OK as well. ActiveX is absolutely out of question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[System.Web.HttpRequest.UserHostname](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostname?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpRequest_UserHostName) as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17691/1011722) just returns the IP :-(

But I just found this:

```
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Page.Request.UserHostAddress).HostName
```

That only works if there is actually a DNS Server to resolve the name, which is the case for my network.

Answer (score 3):

Does [System.Web.HttpRequest.UserHostname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostname.aspx) provide what you're looking for?