# How can I get the computer name of the client filling an web-based Infopath form?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, moss, infopath

I have an Infopath 2007 form hosted on MOSS 2007. The code behind the form is written in C#. In this context, `System.Environment.MachineName` return the server name.

How can I get the name of the computer from which the client is filling this form?

Answer (score 1):

Would ASP.NET's Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") help?

Comment: I did tried this method using a web service, but it returns the server IP address.

Answer (score 1):

If it's over the Internet: You can't get the PC Name AFAIK (which is a good thing).

If it's on an internal Network, maybe a DNS Lookup would work, [as outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17664/retreiving-the-pc-name-of-a-client-windows-auth)?

Comment: The DNS lookups are working fine, but I can only get the IP address of the Sharepoint server which hosts the Infopath forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a rule and assign any field you like the value from this xpath: **xdUser:get-UserName()**. This returns the users login name.

Comment: I can get the user login name in more than one way, but I am trying to get the computer name (DNS name or NetBIOS name) from which the user is accesing the Infopath form.